# Loading datestamped excel filename c#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm generating an excel file with a timestamp in the name via SSIS, and now I want to format it and make it pretty, for which I am planning to use C# and the Aspose library. The file names will be "Schedule_YYYYMMDDHHMM.xls" in a static directory of C:\schedules.

How can I open the most recent file based on the timestamp?

Comment: This question is unrelated to Excel.

Comment: Unrelated to your question; Are you really generating `.xls` files. OpenXML files are better in just about every way

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to load all the filenames and sort them. Then use the first one.

Comment: As far as sorting, I'm trying to use string.compare after substringing the data.
thisFile = file.Substring(64, 6);
if(string.Compare(thisFile, lastFile) = 1)
Hovering over thisFile shows the program recognizes it as "(local variable) string thisFile.
I'm getting an error for the compare function where the left-hand side must be a variable

Comment: Just sort the file names, no need for substring or anything. Simply a LINQ order by followed by `FirstOrDefault`